# How To delete items Array in objects state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm want the each items Array in objects state  delete

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      storeData: [{
          "code": "f1",
          "name": "storage-no-1",
          "capacity": 125,
          "temperture": -18,
          "humidity": 3,
          "saveProducts": [{
              "code": "P1",
              "id": "1",
              "name": "product-no-1",
              "size": 20,
            },
            {
              "code": "P1",
              "id": "2",
              "name": "product-no-2",
              "size": 20,
            },
          ]
        },
        {
          "code": "f2",
          "name": "storage-no-2",
          "capacity": 15,
          "temperture": -18,
          "humidity": 25,
          "saveProducts": [{
              "code": "P1",
              "id": "1",
              "name": "product-no-1",
              "size": 20,
            },
            {
              "code": "P1",
              "id": "2",
              "name": "product-no-2",
              "size": 20,
            },
          ]
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

my function code :

```
deleteItem = (saveProductsId,storeCode) => {
console.log("obj",saveProductsId)
console.log("ttt",storeCode);
this.setState(prevState => {
prevState.storeData.map(store => {
    if (store.code == storeCode) {
      return {
        ...store,
        saveProducts: [
            ...store.saveProducts.filter(product => product !==  saveProductsId)
        ]
      };
    } else { 
      return store;
    }
  })
})
};
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: I've just realized that `saveProducts` is an array. You want to remove the items from each of `saveProducts` inside each `storeData` object?

Comment: yes i want this

Comment: I have updated the answer. If it does't work, I'll delete it

Answer (score 4):

Go through each item in `storeData` and [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `saveProducts` where the `id !== saveProductsId`:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
      const storeData = prevState.storeData.map(s => 
          ({ ...s, saveProducts: s.saveProducts.filter(p => p.id !== saveProductsId) }));
      return { storeData };
  })
```

Comment: @A.RR Are there any objects in `storeData` which don't have a `saveProducts` property?

Comment: No, all objects have saveProducts property

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue but you're missing a comma after `"humidity": 3` and `"humidity": 25`. Just before `saveProducts` declaration in `state`

Comment: I want to remove the selected item from the saveProducts

Comment: No, I meant the `"humidity": 3` in the `storeData` array

Comment: This answer is the correct one. It seems the question has been updated a few times and there are other bugs in it now. Like in your first setState example you're returning `item` which is undefined. Your second example doesn't follow the answer here because this answer has 2 array methods (map and filter) and you need both.

Comment: @tenor528 please check my code and help me to fix function(deleteItem)

Comment: @adiga please check my code and help me to fix function(deleteItem)